# Get a list of enumeration values in Kotlin for an Any variable

Tags: kotlin, enums

How can I retrieve the list of enum values in Kotlin for a variable of Any type? There are plenty of questions on how to print the list of enum values, but these all start from a known enum class. How can I get the list of enum values for a variable that is an enum?

```
    import kotlin.reflect.full.isSubclassOf    
enum class Direction { NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST }
enum class Days { MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAY, SUN }

fun main(){
    val x1: Any = Direction.NORTH
    val x2: Any = Days.TUE
    val x3: Any = 100.0

    printEnumValues(x1)// should print NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST
    printEnumValues(x2)// should print MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAY, SUN 
    printEnumValues(x3)// should print nothing.
}

fun printEnumValues(arg : Any)
{
    if (arg::class.isSubclassOf(Enum::class)){
        // How to get and print the list of possible enum values here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it can be done with Kotlin reflection, but you can borrow Java reflection to do it like this:

```
fun printEnumValues(arg: Any) {
  if (arg is Enum<*>) {
    println(arg::class.java.enumConstants.joinToString())
  }
}
```